# Does the aid another "special attack" become automatic at mid level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack

Under PF core rulebook page 197 it states that ["Aid Another](http://paizo.com/prd/combat.html#_aid-another)" is an attack roll against AC 10.  Some of our first level characters have a +5 to hit.  When level 5 is reached, a fighter could easily have +12 or so.  A rogue, monk or ranger +10 with a feat or two and great stats.  That would seem to indicate that to hit +10 is automatic (barring a natural 1). Was this the intention of the game?  I'm going to assume that the idea is that a level 5 character should have something better to do than aid another.  But would it not be beneficial in a situation where an enemy becomes fixated on a character and you have an opportunity to boost his AC by +2?

Comment: Side note: In my experience, Aid Another usually comes up at mid-levels when low-level summons/thralls/suicidal cohorts perform it for the benefit of a mid-level PC.

Comment: I once ran a module which had an encounter with 10th level PCs against an army of 100 2nd level orcs.  The orcs all did aid another on each other so that one of them could hit.  The PCs slaughtered them, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

The Aid Another action gets a lot easier as you gain levels, to the point where it's nearly automatic for all characters at mid to high levels.  This is probably for two reasons:

1. At higher levels, you likely have much better things to do than give +2 to AC or an attack roll.
2. At higher levels, +2 means a lot less than at low levels.

If my attack roll is already a +10, then adding another 2 isn't that big of a deal.  However, at early levels, if my attack roll is only +3, adding an extra 2 is a big deal.  Likewise with AC.

Comment: +2 can be useful at any level; think of the final chance to hit, not the actual bonus to attack. If you only hit on a 19+, then another +2 to hit will double your odds of success. Similarly, if you hit on a 4+, then another +2 won't do much--regardless of your level. Since enemies scale up with the players, the raw bonus to hit isn't as meaningful as the relative difference between attack bonus and AC.

Comment: @PaulMarshall - You're entirely right, but attack bonuses scale faster than AC does.  So while +2 provides a +10% chance to hit regardless of level, going from 70% to 80% feels much less useful than going from 15% to 25%.